# How do insert multivariate dict in Tensorflow's NumpyReader?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

the answer must be really simple, but I cannot wrap my head around the exact implementation of this:

> Multivariate; TIMES is a vector of shape [series length], VALUES has shape [series length x number of features].

in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/timeseries/NumpyReader

It seems to work fine in univariate as:

```
            import numpy as np

            status = []
            time = []

            #sensorstatus provides the values for the lists
            for ss in sensorstatus:
                status.append(int(ss.status))
                time.append(ss.time.timestamp())

            status = np.array(status)
            time = np.array(time)

            data = {
                tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.TIMES: time,
                tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.VALUES: status,
            }

            reader = NumpyReader(data)
```

but how could I add another list into the data as tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.VALUES ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue with:

```
combine = list(zip(status, weekdays))
```

and also remebered to add:

```
num_features=2
```

in ARRegressor.

Hope this helps someone!